# How to make bootstrap columns with images responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

For example if I have

```
<style type="text/css">
#box{
    height: 130px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That will looked like

```
   box     box     box    
   box     box     box
```

Then after the window is resize it will become like this

```
   box  
   box
   box
   box
   box
   box
```

What I want is if I resize the window to lets say width of 766 pixels it will become like this

```
   box     box
   box     box 
   box     box
```

Then after a smaller window then it will become like

```
   box  
   box
   box
   box
   box
   box
```

I want it to be like 3 transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstraps build-in column system automatically takes care of this issue in case of a single row. I changed your code to work accordingly.

`col-md-4`:
On medium screens, use 4 columns of the basic 12(suits 3)

`col-sm-6`:
On small media, use 6 columns of the basic 12(suits 2)

`col-xs-12`: 
On tiny media, use 12 columns of the basic 12 (suits 1)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Bootstrap rows won't do it like that. https://gyazo.com/26040b75c7a3f411b62df81b068224c7

Comment: It's because you have them in seperate `<div class='row'></div>` elements, try again with the new code.

Comment: Also, your `margin: 10px` CSS is breaking this.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries provided by bootstrap follow the link below

[Media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: You can't use media queries in HTML, so how are you going to create another row div?

Comment: @PoprostuRonin I know css is  require but its up to him how he does it

Comment: i know about media queries but what am i gonna do about the div's do i still edit them inside the media queries?

Comment: @Otachan i think that media queries will be the smart and easiest one  u still can still achive by any other way  now its up to u.... best luck